# Printing on console function name in pytest parallel to the script running

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have attached a simple python script that needs to be tested(attached the image).for running this script it takes around 3-5 minutes. So while the script is running can i print on console like this -"Running subtest test_device_discovery"
After the execution of this on console it should be printed  like
Running subtest test_device_discovery-passed (or failed)

So is this possible in pytest?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVCXX.jpg)

Comment: Hi, this should be the default output of a pytest run: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html#get-started . If everthing works as expected you will get this without any extra work.

Comment: I want the above things at the run time not after the completion of the script.Suppose now function 'a' of script is running so it should print function a is running after that suppose it is running function b so it should change the message on console  function 'b' of script is running or something like that